# Error on cross request: "Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, include

I'm trying to load content from one of my sites in another:

```
<div id='include-from-outside'></div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $('#include-from-outside').load('http://lujanventas.com/plugins/banner/index.php&callback=?');
</script>
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://lujanventas.com/plugins/banner/index.php&callback=?. Origin http://lventas.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

How can I prevent it from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url you are using suggests the site supports JSONP (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). If so, you should be able to do it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function handleResponse(json){
       var data = JSON.parse(json);
       ...handle data...
    }
</script>
<script src="http://lujanventas.com/plugins/banner/index.php?callback=handleResponse"></script>
```

Comment: +1 -- For IE < 8, use `$.parseJSON(json)` since you already have jQuery included.

Comment: I just tried your code and it seems to bypass the error. However I'm getting `500 internal server error` what can be the reason for this (I copied the code and made no changes to it).

Comment: Yeah I tried it too, and I noticed the 500. It seems the server is either not willing to accept the callback parameter, or there is a bug on their side. I figured, since you mentioned that url in the first place, you know what you're doing. If I'd be you I'd check with whomever gave you the url if you got it right (no typos etc)

Comment: Just a question, I started using CORS but it was unusable on old browsers. Will this be more cross-browser compatible?

Comment: Can any site be turned into JSON? I'm trying to figure it out since I never did it. I will have to make all php output JSON format right?

Comment: Not "all" php output. If you know something is simply content that has to be rendered as html/css, that is best returned by the server in the right format. But I thought you said you can't control the site anyway...this question is starting to confuse me.

Comment: Oh, I just wanted to add that JSONP is technically not JSON, it's javascript, since your output is essentially text that is to be interpreted at the client side as a javascript function call, where the data is passed as a single argument to that function. JSON would be only the plain data, which the client would explicitly parse using a JSON parser to turn it into a javascript object structure.

Answer (score 3):

There are two options:

1: make http://lujanventas.com return proper CORS headers -- http://enable-cors.org/

2: request the html using your server instead of with js in the browser -- http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/code/216729/php-proxy-solution-for-cross-domain-ajax-scripting

Comment: How can I add the CORS response headers. I just readed a lot but I don't know where I must add them. How can I request the HTML using the server? I can't think of any other way.

Comment: This page outlines how to add CORS response headers in various environments: http://enable-cors.org/ As far as requesting it using the server, here's a good article for php: http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/code/216729/php-proxy-solution-for-cross-domain-ajax-scripting

Comment: The first option seems more likely, I just read the page. It says `Granting JavaScript clients basic access to your resources simply requires adding one HTTP response header, namely Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` but where do I add this line? I'm sorry but this is new territory for me

Comment: @Liso22 - Read farther down the page, it explains how to do it multiple ways based on what environement you use.

Comment: I hadn't read about htaccess I created a file and added the line. However I am now getting a 505 server error. What could be the cause? I'll submit it later as a new question

Comment: @Liso22 did you ensure that `mod_headers` is enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery ajax to query a php file that loads lujaventas content then the ajax callback will be lujaventas content.

Comment: I get your method. But I cannot use it since I need to distribute the div+script as a plugin

Comment: you could also use jsonp , you would need to make the banner format as json format and this would work on every browser(cors is an extension)